# Why is an extra bullet point showing in my link navigation?

Tags: html, css

I have the same basic navigation structure for all my websites.  As you can tell I have a space between the contact us and the pixels on my website:  http://thenewfilmsandfluff.blogspot.com/2015/09/hitman-47.html

Given the fact that it looks like this on all my relevant websites I think it is sufficient enough to include both the HTML and CSS for the relevant structure.  I use the advanced template layout to mark-up my HTML with CSS.

This is what the HTML looks like for my navigation section- I've made it in comments so that it would still be able to show.

```
 Context:  this is the code navigation for my website.  
     <!--<section id="nav">
    <nav><ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hitman 47!!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Minions!!  </a></li>
      <li><a href= #">Selected Reviews #1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Terminator Genisys</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Adjustment Bureau</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Jurassic World</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Inside Out</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Star Wars IV: A New Hope</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Star Wars V:  The Empire Strikes Back</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a><li>
    <li><a href="#">Pixels!</a></li></ul></nav>

I've included the # to denote examples.  

 </section> -->

    And here is the CSS for the section

/*
h2{color:  #00CCFF; border: 1px; background-color:  blue; border-radius: 10px; -MOZ-BORDER-RADIUS:  10PX; -webkit-border-radius:  10px; -moz-box-shadow:  10px 10px; -webkit-box-shadow:  10px 10px;  }
h2.style{font-size: 35px;}
p.style2{font-size:  20px; color: #0000FF !important; font-family:  ariel, times new-roman; background-color: lawngreen;}
body{background-color: beige;}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    display: inline;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #dddddd;

body{background-color:  mediumpurple;}

}

a:link{color:  #CC3300; }
a:visited{color:  #D14719;}
a:hovor{color:  #D65C33; background-color: blueviolet;}
a:active{color: #661A00;}

section#main{float: left;
    width: 70%;}
Section#nav{float:right;
width:  20%;}*/
```

What is it that I could be doing?

Comment: It's a typo: You have an opening `<li>` tag after `Contact</a>` instead of a closing `</li>` tag. You're also missing the opening parenthesis in the anchor tag for "Selected Reviews #1". Flagging for: *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.*

Comment: Man, I understand your plight, but that meta link has **-18** points!

Answer (score 0):

You didnt close the li tag for contact

```
<li><a href="#">Contact</a><li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

You missed a doubled quote here by href

```
<li><a href= #">Selected Reviews #1</a></li>
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="#">Contact</a><li> //(You didnt close the li tag for contact)

It should be like this:

<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Modern browsers will parse the html automatically and close the unclosed tags so its rendering like:

```
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> and empty list item <li></li>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still getting used to trouble-shooting code so I recognize this was a post that I could have prevented.